# Score not working, int ++ not incrementing in label

Tags: c#, silverlight, label, increment

I have a program that counts collisions.

**Code**

```
int eatenAppleCount = 0;

public MainPage()
{
score.Content = "Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(eatenAppleCount);   
}

 for (int indx = myapples.Count - 1; indx >= 0; indx--)
            {
                myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);
                bool collided = DetectCollision(myapples[indx], myPig);
                if (collided)
                {
                    eatenAppleCount ++;
                    RemoveApple(myapples[indx]);
                }
            }
```

Problem is the score just reads 0 even on collisions.
Can someone help me and I do not understand why it is not incrementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your code for calculating `eatenAppleCount` before showing it in the message.

It appears you are just using the default value of `eatenAppleCount` and then you are calculating it.

```
int eatenAppleCount = 0;

public MainPage()
{

    for (int indx = myapples.Count - 1; indx >= 0; indx--)
    {
        myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);
        bool collided = DetectCollision(myapples[indx], myPig);
        if (collided)
        {
            eatenAppleCount ++;
            RemoveApple(myapples[indx]);
        }
    }

    score.Content = "Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(eatenAppleCount);   

}
```

Comment: Ahh amazing, put the label in wrong place. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You got several code snipets so hard to follow a bit, but I think you just need to reapply this line after the increment:

```
score.Content = "Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(eatenAppleCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a variable to create a string to use as content doesn't link that variable to the content. When the variable changes, it doesn't affect content created from the previous value.

You need to update the content when the variable changes. Put that code from the constructor in a method, so that you can call it both from the constructor, and when you want to update the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass this variable as reference

```
int eatenAppleCount = 0;

public MainPage()
{
   CollisionDetect(ref eatenAppleCount);
   score.Content = "Score" + " " + Convert.ToString(eatenAppleCount);   
}

protected void CollisionDetect(ref eatenAppleCount)
{
    for (int indx = myapples.Count - 1; indx >= 0; indx--)
    {
         myapples[indx].Update(LayoutRoot);
         bool collided = DetectCollision(myapples[indx], myPig);
         if (collided)
         {
             eatenAppleCount ++;
             RemoveApple(myapples[indx]);
         }
     }        
}
```

Comment: reference ?? where ? to `Convert.ToString` ?

Comment: @NewHire Well, is possible if you use some OO in this code because you'll need split some responsabilities from the main method.